# How to save dynamic radio name into session array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a registration page where the user can choose a program and its time (if the program has more than one time). I want to save the program and the chosen time into a session to pass them through multiple pages. The problem is that the time radios have a concatenated name with the course id. How to post the radio name and store it in a session.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM programs Where status = 'open'";
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);
$stmt3->execute();
$result3 = $stmt3->get_result();
$stmt3->close();

while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $courseName = $row3['courseName'];
    $coursePrice = $row3['coursePrice'];
    $courseId = $row3['progId'];
    $multiTime = $row3['multiTime'];
                   
    $programList .= ' 
        <div class="form-check proDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" name="course[]"  class="form-check-input group2" id="'.$coursePrice.'" value="'.$courseId.'">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="'.$coursePrice.'">'.$courseName .' price is '.$coursePrice.'$</label> 
        </div>';

    if($multiTime >=1){                                  
        $sql4 = "SELECT * 
                    FROM weekDaysTime 
                    Where programId =  $courseId";

        $stmt4 = $conn->prepare($sql4);
        $stmt4->execute();
        $result4 = $stmt4->get_result();
     
        while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {
            $timeFrom = $row4['timeFrom'];
            $timeTo = $row4['timeTo'];
            $dateFrom = $row4['dateFrom'];
            $dateTo = $row4['dateTo'];
                                        
            $programList .= '
                <div name="timeDiv'.$courseId.'" class="timeGroup">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timeRadio" value="Weekday" name="time'.$courseId.'" />
                        <label class="form-check-label"><strong>Weekdays</strong> From'.$timeFrom.' To 
       '.$timeTo.' <br>Date From '.$dateFrom.' To '.$dateTo.'</label>
                </div>';
                       
        }
        $stmt4->close();

        $sql5 = "SELECT * 
                FROM weekendsTime   
                Where programId =  $courseId";
        $stmt5 = $conn->prepare($sql5);
        $stmt5->execute();
        $result5 = $stmt5->get_result();

        while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) {
            $endTimeFrom = $row5['endTimeFrom'];
            $endTimeTo = $row5['endTimeTo'];
            $endDateFrom = $row5['endDateFrom'];
            $endDateTo = $row5['endDateTo'];

            $programList .= '
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timeRadio" 
       value="weekend"  name="time'.$courseId.'" />
                <label class="form-check-label"><strong>Weekend 
       </strong>From'.$endTimeFrom.' To '.$endTimeTo.' <br>Date From 
       '.$endDateFrom.' To '.$endDateTo.'</label>
            </div>
        </div>';
        }
        $stmt5->close();                           
    }
} 
echo $programList;
```

Comment: Try to use foreach loop during the handling of the form with PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the relevant part

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timeRadio" value="Weekday" name="time'.$courseId.'" />
```

You've named your checkboxes `course[]`. What you might not know is you can treat it like a PHP array. Just modify it to

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="timeRadio" value="Weekday" name="time['.$courseId.']" />
```

When you process it, you'll run through it like

```
foreach($_POST['time'] as $courseId => $value) { 
    // your loop here 
}
```

or

```
$_POST['time'][$courseId]
```

This way, your `$courseId` will be associated with the value